# Registering Broadcast Receiver at runtime?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I know we can register a broadcast receiver at runtime with `registerreceiver()` method and then later unregister it with `unregisterreceiver()` .

I remember reading about a method which will make our receiver the only receiver i.e. only our receiver will receive broadcasts on that particular action . Is there any method like this ?

Also is there a way of knowing if the particular receiver is registered or not ?

Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LocalBroadcastManager` which registers for and sends broadcasts of Intents to local objects within your process

Comment: thanks for your answer .LocalBroadcastManager seems like a useful tool but not exactly what i wanted .I think it was just an hallucination that i read about a method something like that.

i got to know about the ordered broadcasts which solved my problem .